# history.push no se ejecuta en el componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, props

Estoy tratando de hacer un `history.push('/home')` para que la aplicacion vuelva al inicio en caso dado que una persona limpie el caché o localStorage (Uso redux persist). El asunto es que hay una página donde tengo una serie de cotizaciones que dependen de los dato de unos formularios que el usuario llena unos pasos atrás. Sin embargo, al recargar despues de haber limpiado caché me da error puesto que el metodo render hace renderizado de ciertas props que ya no estarán al limpiar caché. Tambien la idea es mandar al usuario al inicio para que que antes de realizar la cotizacion llene ciertos formularios. Estoy haciendo esa validación en el componentDidmount y mi código es así:

```
componentDidMount() {
  
    const {
      marca,
      modelo, 
      anocarro, 
      email2,
    } = this.props;

    if(!marca || !modelo || !anocarro || !email2) {
     this.props.history.push('/FullCoverage');
    }
   
    scroller.scrollTo("global_top", {
      smooth: true,
      offset: window.innerWidth > 900 ? -150 : -120,
    });
  }
```

La conexion a redux es así:

```
 const CCFormSelector = formValueSelector("DTForm");
    
 function mapstateToProps(state) {
   return {
     email2: CCFormSelector(state, "email"),
     marca: CCFormSelector(state, "marca"),
     modelo: CCFormSelector(state, "modelo"),
     anocarro: CCFormSelector(state, "ano"),
   }
 }
```

Ya por ultimo hago un export default withRouter para usar las props del router. ¿Por qué cuando limpio caché no funciona el history push en el didMount?

Comment: Si pudieras compartir el mensaje de error, saludos